# whileInView and whileHover conflicting

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

I have a grid component and a card component that goes inside this.  I wanted to animate each child of the grid whileInView so I added this prop to the parent and was working properly.

The problem comes when I try to add whileHover prop to the childs, it causes the whileInView prop to be disabled. I have also tried to add it on the parent but it makes the grid to anime as a whole.

**Grid component**:

```
<SmallGridSection key={`div-${title}`}>
    <SmallGrid
        key={`grid-${title}`}
        variants={gridVariants}
        initial={"hidden"}
        whileInView={"visible"}
        viewport={{ once: true }}
        >

        {array.map(
            technology =>

            <Card technology={technology} key={technology.name}/>
        )}
    </SmallGrid>
</SmallGridSection>
```

using this variants:

```
const gridVariants = {
    visible: {
        transition: {
            when: "beforeChildren",
            delayChildren: 1,
            staggerChildren: 0.1,
        },
    },
    hidden: {
        transition: {
            when: "afterChildren",
            duration: 1,
            type: "spring",
        },
    },
}
```

**Card component:**

```
const Card = ({ technology, ...props }) => {

    return(
        <CardStyled
            color={technology.color}
            variants={cardVariants}
            title={technology.name}

            (   *this is where i tried to add "whileHover={"hovered"}*)

            {...props}
            >
                <a>
                    <TechnologyIcon technology={technology}/>
                </a>
        </CardStyled>
    )
}
```

with this variants:

```
const cardVariants = {
    hidden: { 
        opacity: 0, 
        rotate: "100deg"
    },
    visible: { 
        opacity: 1,
        rotate: 0, 
    },
    animated: {
        translateY: "-5px",
        transition: {
            type: "spring",
            delay: 3,
            duration: 0.5,
            repeat: "infinity",
        },
    },
    hovered: {
        scale: 1.08,
        transition: {
            duration: 0.2,
            ease: "easeInOut",
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon this problem as well and managed to solve it by applying whileInView and whileHover to different levels, not to one element. So you need to wrap your card content into another div (or whatever you want) and apply whileHover to it as well as variants with the hover property (actually, the whole cardVariants will work as well):

```
<CardStyled
    color={technology.color}
    variants={cardVariants}
    title={technology.name}
>
    <motion.div
        whileHover="hovered"
        variants={{
            hover: cardVariants.hovered,
        }}
    >
        <a>
            <TechnologyIcon technology={technology}/>
        </a>
    </motion.div>
</CardStyled>
```

Of course, it would make sense to move the new div into your CardStyled component, but the overall structure should look this way.